# Using gRPC on localhost

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, grpc

I want to use gRPC for IPC, on localhost, using C++, in particular for Windows machines. I would like to avoid using https, and I wonder whether the non-secure http poses any threat. I would like to use the UDS solution but this is only supported in C# and not C++. I could use C# and CLI to provide the functionality to C++, but I have a blocker with the C# version.

So I am left with the option to either use https or implement something myself. However this is becoming unchartered territory for me. I would therefore like to ask, what do people think are my options?

I tried to find a way to implement a transport layer using e.g. pipes only for Windows as a plugin, but documentation is scarce...

Comment: Questions that can only be answered with opinions are discouraged on Stack overflow. Your question may be down-voted/closed.

Comment: IIUC IMO (!) you should use HTTP (non-TLS) and bind to localhost to avoid remote peers accessing your server. You've got the transport layer hit but you save a bunch of proprietary coding, testing and maintaining.

Comment: "I would like to use the UDS solution but this is only supported in C# and not C++" - Citation needed. I'm pretty sure C++ solutions exist for this.

Comment: @JesperJuhl not on Windows

Comment: @dpservis I was not commenting on niche operating systems 

Comment: By the "UDS solution only supported in C#" are you referring to Unix Domain Sockts?

Comment: @dan-kli yes this is what I mean

Comment: Yeah, Unix Sockets worked fine for me when I implemented Inter-Process Communication with gRPC (in C#, as you said). Maybe if you just rephrase the question a bit, like "How can I implemented inter-process communication with gRPC in C++ without using HTTPS" it is not "opinion-based" anymore?

Comment: Thanks @dan-kli, I did not ask for opinions, I asked for options. That said, the vast majority of SO responses are highly opinionated.

Comment: True, you did. Anyway, some of the best answers you find on SO are opinion-based (in my opinion, haha..). I preferred the old SO where you could just ask any tech-related question...

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems in the course of being resolved

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/34801